# Separating a string with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on a VERY simple search feature for my website. The user types in their search query and then they are taken to a page that displays the results. In my case, the users are search for other users. My problem is, how do I separate a string into two variables?

Example Query:

Matt Morris

I would like my PHP to separate the string where the space occurs. How can I do that?

```
  <html>
    <form method="get" action="results.php">
        <input type="text" name="search"/>
    </form>

 </html>

<?php

    // code to explode the string into $fname and $lname 
       if there is a space present

$fname= Matt
$lname= Morris

if (isset($fname) && isset($lname)) {
$search_query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE %'".$fname."'% AND lname LIKE  
%'".$lname."'%";
// code to run the query and display results
}
else if (isset($fname)) {
$search_query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE %'".$fname."'%";
// code to run the query and display results
}
else if (isset($lname)) {
$search_query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname LIKE %'".$lname."'%";
// code to run the query and display results
}

 ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You gotta watch out with exploding strings and expecting to get fname/lname, there are some people with spaces in their last name (and sometimes first).

Comment: As a savvy user knowing that you do not sanitize anything, I would just enter `Matt%Moris`  as search term.

Comment: What does entering that do? I use mysql_real_escape_string() is that good or outdated?

Comment: Yes, it is, both. It does not escape LIKE pattern placeholders though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
list($first, $last) = explode($name, ' ', 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the php function explode
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Answer (score 2):

`$array = explode(' ', $string);`